# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT is outputting duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

This query is set to SELECT DISTINCT.  However, I get duplicates.  It's supposed to show two random page titles / images:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    `$page_type`.title AS title,
    page_images.image_loc AS images
    FROM `$page_type`, page_images
    WHERE page_images.url_title = `$page_type`.url_title AND
    `$page_type`.url_title != '$spot'
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

Any idea why this is outputting duplicates?

Comment: Please post an example duplicate.

Comment: May want to apply [grouping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/54430/298053) (Though this is applicable example applies to postgresql)

Comment: I tried gouping / DISTINCTROW.  Same result though.  Duplicate titles show up on every few page refreshes.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when it looks like SELECT DISTINCT is returning duplicates, there are subtle differences between lines that look the same (because of whitespace or because of encoding issues such as combining pairs).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the contents of your tables or seeing the output it's hard to see where the duplication is coming from. You could have unique url_titles but happen to have a title that is the same for different url_titles, for example. (I'm assuming you don't have a typo and mean 'url_title' rather than 'title' in the 2nd line).

To come at the query a different way (and to eliminate duplicate titles) you could refactor the query to be nested and look like this for both clarity and efficiency and see what you get. I think it might solve the symptoms of your problem. The sub-query gets you unique titles, the main query pairs up the images for you.

```
SELECT
    `$page_type`.title AS title,
    page_images.image_loc AS images
    FROM `$page_type`, page_images
    WHERE page_images.url_title = `$page_type`.url_title AND
    `$page_type`.title IN

(SELECT DISTINCT
    `$page_type`.title
    FROM `$page_type`
    WHERE `$page_type`.url_title != '$spot'
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
```

Doing the sub-query in this way eliminates RAND() running over the table join. Generally ORDER BY RAND() is inefficient for large tables, be warned (but we love it just the same).